# Where is The third Gisella prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

A Gisella prime is a prime number obtained from concatenating the first $n$ natural numbers starting from $2$ and then replace each composite on that concatenation with the concatenation of its prime factors in ascending order, i.e: $23456789101112$ transformed to $23225237222332511223$. The first two Gisella primes are $2$ and $23$. I have checked $n$ up to $1000$, but I couldn't find other primes. Could you find the third Gisella prime?

Comment: Quite a difficult problem, and the OEIS is of little help here. `2, 23` gives way too many results.

Comment: No solutions below $2500$.

Comment: Why did you choose to start concatenating numbers from 2 and not from 1?

Comment: @RobertSoupe the sequences $2,23,2322,23225...$ and $1,12,123,12322...$ are not in the OEIS so I think it's safe to assume that the one containing only primes isn't either

Comment: If we start with 1 then we get 6 (12322523), 27, 53, 2179, 3539.  Nothing else to 4200.  Starting with 2, nothing past 2 and 23 out to 12400.

Starting at two makes sense, as factor(1) returns the empty set in most systems.